# time complexity for 3 foor loops different leangth

Tags: python, complexity, runtime

I have this method

```
arr // input


new_ seq = []

for i in arr:
  new_seq.append(i)
  __new_seq = [x for i, x in enumerate(arr) if x not in new_seq]
  for j in __new_seq:
      new_seq.append(j)
      __new_seq = [x for i, x in enumerate(arr) if x not in new_seq]
      for k in __new_seq:
          new_seq.append(k)
```

How to calculate the time complexity for this method
Please note that each loop has a smaller length than the one before

Comment: What is the purpose of the code?

Comment: this is just a small chunk of a greedy code to generate new sequence.

Comment: Why `x for i, x in enumerate(arr)` and not `x for x in arr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily, a loop that executes only part of the time counts as a normal loop - complexity analysis ignores constant factors. That would make it cubic time complexity.

In this case, though, the inner loops *never* execute, so it should be quadratic time (the middle loop body never executes, but you still spend time iterating the second `for`...`in`).

Comment: Please see the updated code.  
The first loop takes all the arr elements O(n)
The second and the third loop takes all the elements that has not been added to the new_seq 
this is not O(n)^3 .... I think its less than that

Comment: Just to clarify your answer => time complexity for this code is O(n) ?
Regardless the time needed for the second the the third loop?!!

Comment: @FarahAmawi That's how big O works. Doesn't mater how big or small constant factors are.